# CameraView.setLifecycleOwner(this) callback in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, camera-view

I am trying to integrate [this](https://github.com/natario1/CameraView) library in my fragment. In this tutorial they have said to call fragment.viewLifecycleOwner instead of this in camera.setLifecycleOwner(this). I have followed all the process to start video recording. I tried to debug it also but after calling camera.startCapturingVideo(file) its not getting a callback for onVideoTaken(). My video file is getting created in the path but while playing it, it's showing can't play this video.I think it's because I am not getting a callback.
Below is my Fragment:

```
     public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            covered = InhalerData.getInstance().manifest.getPlayerType();

            if (covered != null) {
                if (covered.equalsIgnoreCase("covered")) {
                    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_video, container, false);
                } else {
                    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_video_side_by_side, container, false);
                }
            }
            mContext = getActivity();

            setViews();
            return view;

        }

        private void setViews() {
            //initializing views
            video = view.findViewById(R.id.video);
            textureView = view.findViewById(R.id.camera_texture);
            parentLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
            overLay = view.findViewById(R.id.overlay);
            tv_tips = view.findViewById(R.id.tips);
            textureView.setLifecycleOwner(VideoPlayerFragment.this);
                    return true;
                }
            });

            textureView.addCameraListener(new CameraListener() {
                @Override
                public void onVideoTaken(File video) {
                    super.onVideoTaken(video);
                    onVideo(video);
                }
            });

        }
//This method is called on record button click
     private void captureVideo(String name) {
          if (textureView.getSessionType() != SessionType.VIDEO) {
                return;
            }
            isRecordingOn = false;
            File mediaFile =
                    new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                            + "/" + name + VIDEO_EXTENSION);
            textureView.setVideoCodec(VideoCodec.H_264);
            textureView.startCapturingVideo(mediaFile, 8000);
            if (mRecordingTimer != null) {
                mRecordingTimer.start();
            }
            startBlinking();
            textureView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // This will trigger onVideoTaken().
                    textureView.stopCapturingVideo();
                }
            }, 8000);

    }
```

How can I add a callBack in fragment, What should I pass instead of this.

Comment: they suggest you do this: camera.setLifecycleOwner(fragment.viewLifecycleOwner()); have you tried that instead?

Comment: I have read this but I am not sure what is fragment? I tried to create fragment instance and call that method nut unfortunately that is also not working.

Comment: From the activity that serves as a wrapper for your fragment, you call that before you begin the fragment transaction I guess